# Can't make API call mail.Send from com.google.appengine library using MailService

Tags: java, maven, email, google-app-engine, service

the problem is that i integrate com.google.appengine in my maven project and i want to send mails using the MailService, but it throws me exception that i do not know how to resolve. It is throwing me: "Can't make API call mail.Send in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager". Can you help me how to fix it ? Here is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.73</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the code:

```
MailService mailService = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setSender("dilian_1995@abv.bg");
        message.setTo("dilyangalabov@gmail.com");
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setTextBody("Testt");

        try {
            mailService.send(message);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make mail send service using javax.mail , here is it . 
"String to " is email you want to send.
 To send via Google  I setPropetry mail.smtp.host to smtp.gmail.com

```
public class MailSend {
  public static boolean main(String to) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.user", "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com");


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("YOUREMAIL@gmail.com"));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject("THEME");
    message.setText("TEXT");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    transport.connect("YOUREMAIL@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();

    return true;
  }
}
```